# Database migrations in Flask without SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, database-migration

Is there any library or tool to perform database migrations in python without SQLAlchemy? I am using a PostgreSQL database and the queries are raw SQL. I use psycopg2 for the database connection.

Comment: you mean migrations without using `flask-migrate` ?

Comment: `psycopg2` is db connection api, with `psycopg2` you have to operate on the database using the standard sql commands, however `flask-SQLAlchemy` is an ORM wrapper built around `SQLAlchemy` and gives you a pythonic interface to the database, so if you want to truly manage a database using python you should be using `SQLAlchemy` or `flask-SQLAlchemy`. The actual migration library in python is `alembic` and `flask-migrate` is a convenient wrapper  built over `alembic`.

Comment: I know but I am working in a project already not using SQLAlchemt and I need to implement database migration. Any suggestions?

Comment: you will have to use alembic and run the migration scripts by yourself manually.

Comment: If I will run the scripts manually what's the use of alembic?

Comment: `alembic` generates the migration scripts for you, it hides the enormous amount of complexity of updating a schema for an existing table in the database. Updating schema of existing tables in the database is a very complex operation and requires careful planning for tables with large number of columns and imagine if you have to do such thing frequently it is even cumbersome. `alembic` in combination with `flask-migrate` makes this task very easy.

Comment: If your application uses pure SQL to query the database, wouldn't it make sense to also write your migrations in pure SQL? It is probably still a good idea to create a table to keep track of which migrations have already run and to make a Python-wrapper to check which migrations should be run and actually run only those migrations, but this seemss reasonably trivial to write. The migrations themselves can be bare SQL files.

Comment: @Zeust the Unoobian 
That's exactly what I ended up doing and it went well. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several tools that can be used to version your database with migrations in Python, outside of SQLAlchemy.  I can't speak for any of them in particular, so I looked for ones that seem to have some adoption as well as active maintainence.

(as of Apr 14, 2023)

| Tool | GitHub | Stars | Maintained | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pgmigrate | [yandex/pgmigrate](https://github.com/yandex/pgmigrate) | 562 | Feb 3 2023 | Postgres only |
| dbmate | [amacneil/dbmate](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate) | 3.3k | Mar 2023 |  |
| Yoyo | [coobas/yoyo-migrations](https://github.com/coobas/yoyo-migrations) | 0 | Mar 2020 |  |
| Migrate | [golang/migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) | 11.2k | Apr 2023 | go-lang library & CLI tool |

Other resources I've found seem to be tied to one framework or another.  Searching the [package index](https://pypi.org/search/?o=&q=migration&page=1) turns up a lot of older resources.

If one finds pgmigrate or dbmate to be undesirable, then from there it might be worth asking whether the migration tool really needs to be Python-specific.  Typically migrations are a part of the build process and (in my opinion) ideally should require as little coding and configuration as possible.

Juan D. Vega's post, [Language and framework agnostic database migrations](https://juanvega.dev/2022/09/09/language-and-framework-agnostic-database-migrations./), highlights the [golang/migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) CLI tool, which attempts to offer a way to manage your migrations irrespective of the particulars of the application that the database supports.

Comment: "Alembic is a lightweight database migration tool for usage with the SQLAlchemy Database Toolkit for Python."

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer So can Alembic be used without SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: @codingbruh No ...

Comment: This **is** a top result on Google, suggest when answering StackOverflow questions you don't just point people back to Google.

Answer (score 1):

There is **[`flask-migratepg`](https://github.com/bezborodow/flask-migratepg)** for this purpose, where SQL files are simply placed under a `database/migrations` directory in alphanumerical order and migrations executed with `flask migrate execute`. It is based on [Psycopg 3](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/).

Answer (score 0):

If you can bring yourself to do your db migrations outside of the CLR, I'd strongly recommend considering [FlyWay](https://flywaydb.org/). It has been around forever, it's supported by RedGate, and the community version is free and open source. It has built-in support for all the major db platforms and installs like any other utility you'd use. For a Python app you'd do all of your db migrations via shell scripts or process calls instead of directly in the code.

My team settled on this tech because:

1. Yoyo is pretty immature and buggy for us
2. We don't use SQLAlchemy's OR framework
3. Alembic's syntax and framework seems pretty heavyweight for us
4. Under FlyWay's model we just write SQL scripts and check them into a directory. It's really lightweight.
5. It's been proven to work nicely in clustered environments

Give it a look.